# How to get the protocol (http or https) of the website using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm just thinking about how we can imitate how browser, say Chrome, detects the protocol of the website with Python. For example we type "stackoverflow.com" on the address bar, then press Enter, browser can automatically detects and change the url to "https://stackoverflow.com" (add website's protocol), I wonder how we can do it in Python, exactly like:

```
url = "stackoverflow.com"
browser = Browser (url) # Browser is a class that we can get website content from url, get its protocol,...
print browser.protocol
```

> https

Is there any library or package that help do this? Thanks a lot.

Edit: My question is unique since other question ask how to redirect to https if we enter http, as I mention, can we automatically detect at the first stage without dummy protocol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Detect is a URL needs to be HTTPS vs HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764639/python-detect-is-a-url-needs-to-be-https-vs-http)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It works for stackoverflow because when you first visit stackoverflow.com on port 80 (the http port), stackoverflow's servers notify the browser that the link has been permanently moved to https.

To detect the same in Python, use the `requests` library, like this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com') # first we try http
>>> r.url # check the actual URL for the site
'https://stackoverflow.com/'
```

To find out how the URL changed, look at the history object, and you will see a 301 response, which means the URI has [moved permanently](https://httpstatuses.com/301) to a new address.

```
>>> r.history[0]
<Response [301]>
>>> r.history[0].url # this is the original URL we tried
'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for something like (at the time of this comment), imgur.com which doesn't redirect http to https. EDIT: However, it seems chrome doesn't try out https first either.

Comment: Cameron: Blurie wanted to imitate the browser so I think this _will_ work.

Comment: Some websites do not redirect to HTTPS if you first visit them with HTTP, so this is not a verified method to check

Comment: this doesn't work for the site hosted on HostGator.

Answer (score 5):

When you enter a url without `http://` or `https://` the browser automatically assumes that you're using `http://` and sends a request on port 80.

If the site redirects you to an `https` site, you'll get two headers of note. One will have a response of [301](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) which indicates a nonerror redirect. The other will be [101](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101) which indicates that you're upgrading your connection type.

You can see this happen if you open a new tab and load `http://stackexchange.com` and watch the packes as they come in on the network tab of your web browser's developer tool suite.

Note:

Both codes are dependent on the host supporting this behavior. Not all websites will automatically redirect you to an `https://` site. Additionally, not all of them support `http2`, so you may not get the `101` upgrade.

If you really want to determine if `https://` is the preferred option, you may want to manually check if it exists when you don't get a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned "browser" and "Chrome" behaviour, one can get the same results as @BurkhanKhalid's really good answer using `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com") #Trying http first
url = driver.current_url

>>> print(url[:url.find(":")])
https
```