# requests.get() not throwing error on the absence of ssl certificate

Tags: html, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

I was trying to write a simple script to check if a website has a ssl certificate or not. I came across some tutorials that suggested to use the requests.get() function with the verify parameter set as to be True but whenever I try to target any website that does not have a SSL certificate the program is not showing any error. The link I am trying to test it on is : http://dtdev.atwebpages.com/
and the code is

```
 import requests
 response = requests.get("http://dtdev.atwebpages.com/", verify = True)
 print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`verify` is for checking whether an `https` certificate is valid or not. So your use-case (i.e. visiting an `http` endpoint) doesn't apply here as there are no certificates to validate.

If you want to check whether or not a website supports `https` you could just try to access its https endpoint and see whether or not you get an error. For example:

```py
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    response = requests.head("https://dtdev.atwebpages.com/")
except ConnectionError:
    print("Figure out why we couldn't connect")
```

In addition:
You also just try to access the `http` endpoint and see whether or not your connection got upgraded. [Like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003098/how-to-get-the-protocol-http-or-https-of-the-website-using-python).